# How to achieve this mosaic effect?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, filter

Which filter should I use to achieve this effect?

[image]

I have applied the dry brush effect on my watercolor-like image. But cannot get the smooth edges like the one above.

[image]

Comment: It looks like the initial example was posterized. I'd suggest on your image to: 1) apply slight guassian blur 2) posterize filter

Answer (score 2):

You're in the wrong application. Not that it can't be created in Photoshop but that was most likely created in a Vector Graphics Application. If you have the Creative Cloud then use Adobe Illustrator and either start from scratch or could just load your progress so far and `Image Trace` it:

[image]

If you don't have Creative Cloud then Inkscape has some auto trace feature as well but I've never used it to know how well it works.